# ASP.NET Core 7 System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

No data is found in my view, when I debug I am getting the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

I am not sure how to debug this further. This code works in another project it is just when I tried to merge it with a new project and have multiple DB contexts and connect strings that I am having the problem.

`AssetsByAssociatesController`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using QsccDevAlpha.Data;

namespace QsccDevAlpha.Controllers
{
    public class AssetsByAssociatesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly QSCC_QAContext _context;

        public AssetsByAssociatesController(QSCC_QAContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult List()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetAssetsByAssociateData()
        {
            var data = _context.AssetsByAssociate.ToList();
            return Json(data);
        }
    }
}
```

`QSCC_QAContext`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using QsccDevAlpha.Models;

namespace QsccDevAlpha.Data;

public partial class QSCC_QAContext : DbContext
{
    public QSCC_QAContext()
    {
    }

    public QSCC_QAContext(DbContextOptions<QSCC_QAContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<AssetsByAssociate> AssetsByAssociate { get; set; }
    // ....
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using QsccDevAlpha.Data;
using QsccDevAlpha.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<QsccDevAlphaDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<QSCC_QAContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("QA_Context")));

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => {
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<IStateProvRepository, StateProvRepository>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
else
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=QSCCWSQL01.QSCC.local;Database=QsccDevAlpha;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;Encrypt=True"

        // How do we want to handle security.  Which account to connect with? Encrypted connections? Etc...
        // ;TrustServerCertificate=True
        // ;Encrypt=False
  },
  "ConnectionStringQA": {
      "QA_Context": "Data Source=QSCCWSQL01.qscc.local;Initial Catalog=QSCC_QA;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Encrypt=True"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<>c.<MoveNext>b__21_0(DbContext _, Enumerator enumerator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at QsccDevAlpha.Controllers.AssetsByAssociatesController.GetAssetsByAssociateData() in C:\Users\tom.estes\source\repos\QsccWebApp\Controllers\AssetsByAssociatesController.cs:line 24
   at lambda_method34(Closure, Object, Object[])
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection: Error: An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server ''.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query: Error: An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'QsccDevAlpha.Data.QSCC_QAContext'.
System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<>c.<MoveNext>b__21_0(DbContext _, Enumerator enumerator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get both connection strings using

```
builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("QA_Context")
```

they need to be in the **same** section called `ConnectionStrings`:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=QSCCWSQL01.QSCC.local;Database=QsccDevAlpha;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;Encrypt=True",
    "QA_Context": "Data Source=QSCCWSQL01.qscc.local;Initial Catalog=QSCC_QA;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Encrypt=True"
}
```